# how to post to page wall by facebook javascript sdk without application

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I know well how to post to a page wall by FB JavaScript SDK.  I first initialize SDK with an application ID and use `FB.api()` call to post to page wall, but when I see that post in Facebook page wall I see it includes "via my application name" text with the post!

I don't want to see it. How do I post to page wall without application ID (like as someone normally post to a page wall) or how to exclude "via my application name" in post? I am trying hard but have not found anywhere solution yet.

Comment: Are you posting as User or as Page?

Comment: so it must that app name appears when posting outside of fb? @anvesh i specify "to" field not any "from" filed so is i am posting as logged in user

Comment: @professional It would be helpful if you could share the snippet of your posting

Comment: well! if you wanted - FB.ui(
  {
 method: 'feed',
 redirect_uri:'http://localhost/joomla2/task-list-test',   
 name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
 link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
 picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
 caption: 'Reference',
 description: 'Dialogs provide a simple',
 to: 116583433622
  },
  function(response) {
 if (response && response.post_id) {
   alert('Post was published.');
 } else {
   alert('Post was not published.');
 }
  }
);